# Stacked Barplot with 3 categories in Plolty

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I need a help creating a Barplot in plotly, any help and suggestion will be much appreciated.

I have a dataframe with columns 'partner', 'weekday', 'time_of_day', 'country', and 'count'. I want to create a stacked bar plot where the x-axis is 'weekday'(0-6), the y-axis is 'count', and each bar is stacked by 'country'. Additionally, I want each 'weekday' to have 4 bins representing the 4 different values of 'time_of_day'(first_6hours,second_6hours,third_6hours,last_6hours). How can I achieve this using matplotlib, seaborn or plotly in Python?

Here are some rows of the data

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vV3j.png)

Here is current code of the barplot

```
import plotly.express as px

x_col = 'weekday'
y_col = 'count'
color_col = 'country'
hover_col = 'country'
title_col = 'partner'

for title in dataframe[title_col].unique():
    fig = px.bar(data_frame=dataframe[dataframe[title_col]==title], x=x_col, y=y_col, color=color_col, hover_name=hover_col,
                 labels={y_col: 'Count'}, facet_col='time_of_day', height=600)
    fig.update_layout(title=f'Distribution by {title_col} {title}')
    fig.show()
```

and one of the output is the following.
[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WacC.png)

Unfortunately it is not the result that I want, I want to that each weekday have 4 bins (representing time_of_day).

If you have some idea please let me know, it can be in other libraries, as well.

Comment: I think it is difficult to graph the data as it is now. From my understanding, I thought it could be handled by calculating count values by country and time_of_day on weekday 0 and then using a loop process to stack them into a bar graph. Just need you to provide your data.

Comment: Unfortunrately I can't give the data, as it is private, thanks though